# How to change format of type Date in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my response I get the field `createdate: "2019-04-19T15:47:48.000+0000"` which is type of `Date` and I want to show it in my grid with a different format e.g. `createdate: "19/04/2019, 18:47:48"` and keep its type.

Now I convert it to string and use this to show it:

```
this.createdate = this.datePipe.transform(this.createdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss');
```

But *datePipe.transform* returns type string like *formatDate*. How can I do it without change the type?

Comment: The `Date` object has no "format". It represents a moment in time. What you see in the console or during debugging is the browser's interpretation of that moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Dates have a specific format so that they can be read easily.

And pipes are used to display data, i.e. it should return a string.

Be careful about the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) : instead of asking this, consider explaining what is your end goal. This would allow us to help you better than helping you implementing bad practices.

Comment: Thank you Maryannah for showing me the right way. I'm new here so I need this kind of help.

Comment: @TheodoreTsg no problem, that's why I'm here for !